# Implementing longest path algorithm in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

I would like some help implementing a longest path algorithm for Haskell. I've only used Haskell for about two weeks and haven't done anything in a functional language before. I am really lost when trying to implement algorithms in a functional language when you are limited to immutable data and recursion.

I've been trying to implement this algorithm: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-longest-path-directed-acyclic-graph/

My graph is constructed like this:

```
data = Graph w = Graph {vertices :: [(Char, w)],
                        edges :: [(Char, Char, w)]} deriving Show
```

So I have weights on both vertices and edges, and the weights can be any datatype. Therefore I also need to take two functions, `f` and `g`, when computing the longest path. The longest path from vertex `a` to `b` will then be the sum of `f(w)` and `g(w)` for all weights in the path.

I have tried implementing this but I always find myself trying to code the "imperative" way, which gets really ugly really fast...

Please point me in the right direction.

```
weight_of_longest_path :: (Ord w) => Graph w -> Char -> Char 
                                             -> (w -> w) -> (w -> w) -> w
weight_of_longest_path  (Graph v w) startVert endVert f g =
  let 
    topSort = dropWhile (/= startVert) $ topological_ordering (Graph v w)
    distList = zip topSort $ 
                 (snd $ head $ filter (\(a,b) -> a == startVert) v) 
                 : (repeat (-999999999))
    finalList = getFinalList (Graph v w) topSort distList f g
  in 
    snd $ head $ filter (\(a,b) -> b == endVert) finalList

getFinalList :: (Ord w) => Graph w -> [Char] -> [(Char, w)] 
                                   -> (w -> w) -> (w -> w) -> [(Char, w)]
getFinalList _  [] finalList _ _ = finalList
getFinalList (Graph v w) (firstVert:rest) distList f g =
  let 
    neighbours = secondNodes $ filter (\(a,b,w) -> a == firstVert) w
    finalList = updateList firstVert neighbours distList (Graph v w) f g
  in  
    getFinalList (Graph v w) rest finalList f g

updateList :: (Ord w) => Char -> [Char] -> [(Char, w)] -> Graph w 
                              -> (w -> w) -> (w -> w) -> [(Char, w)]
updateList _ [] updatedList _ _ _ = updatedList
updateList firstVert (neighbour:rest) distList (Graph vertices weights) f g =
  let 
    edgeWeight = selectThird $ head 
          $ filter (\(a,b,w) -> a == firstVert && b == neighbour) weights
    verticeWeight = snd $ head 
          $ filter (\(a,b) -> a == neighbour) vertices
    newDist = calcDist firstVert neighbour verticeWeight edgeWeight 
                       distList f g
    updatedList = replace distList neighbour newDist
  in  
    updateList firstVert rest updatedList (Graph vertices weights) f g


calcDist :: (Ord w) => Char -> Char -> w -> w -> [(Char, w)] 
                            -> (w -> w) -> (w -> w) -> w
calcDist firstVert neighbour verticeWeight edgeWeight distList f g =
  if (compareTo f g 
         (snd $ head $ filter (\(a,b) -> a == neighbour) distList) 
         (snd $ head $ filter (\(a,b) -> a == firstVert) distList) 
         edgeWeight verticeWeight) == True
  then 
     (f (snd $ head $ filter (\(a,b) -> a == firstVert) distList))
     + (g edgeWeight) + (f verticeWeight)
  else 
     (f (snd $ head $ filter (\(a,b) -> a == neighbour) distList))

replace :: [(Char, w)] -> Char -> w -> [(Char, w)]
replace distList vertice value = 
    map (\p@(f, _) -> if f == vertice then (vertice, value) else p) 
        distList
```

As you can see it's a lot of messy code for such a simple algorithm and I'm sure its doable in a much cleaner way.

Comment: Well, quite a bit of this code could be simplified (and become quite a bit more efficient) if you used `Data.Map` instead of lists for your vertices and edges, it seems that's what you meant.

Comment: Notepad++ counted 2484 characters for the c++ implementation (not including `main()`) on the geeks website you mention, and 1697 characters for yours :)

Comment: Yeah but it feels like I'm not using the power of functional programming, like sending distList from function to function and trying to update it... And some functions just feels like iterators in a way, which is kind of bad.

Comment: This question would be perhaps better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh, thanks Petr. I will post there instead

Comment: wherever you see lots of repeated code it means you miss some abstraction (a function should be defined, and called instead of the repeating code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach that employs a more "functional" way of thinking. It revolves around two functions:

```
longestPath :: Graph -> Node -> Node -> [Edge]
pathCost :: Graph -> [Edges] -> Int
```

`longestPath` returns the path as a list of edges of the longest path. `pathCost` returns the cost of a path.

The definition of `longestPath` goes something like this:

```
longestPath g start end
  | start == end = []
  | otherwise    = 
    maximumBy (comparing (pathCost g))
              [ e : path | e <- edges of the node start
                           let start' = the other vertex of e,
                           let g' = graph g with node start deleted,
                           let path = longestPath g' start' end ]
```

(`maximumBy` comes from `Data.List` and `comparing` from `Data.Ord`)

N.B. The edges will be generated in reverse order.

There are a host of implementation details to figure out, and, in particular, you'll have to slightly modify this to handle the case when there is not a path from `start` to `node` (which can happen once you start deleting nodes), but this is the approach I would start with.

Comment: Thanks alot, that looks like something I could use. I dont really understand maximumBy though, the type definition says 

"(a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> a"

What does it mean if we pass (pathCost g) as the first argument in maximumBy?

Comment: `Ordering` is simply a data type with three values: `LT`, `EQ` and `GT`. A function `a -> a -> Ordering` takes two a's and returns one of these values - i.e. it's a comparison function. `maximumBy` combined with `comparing` picks the "largest" element of a list where "largest" is determined by the function passed to `comparing`.